# can deal with the first line space when i use regex for polynomials

Tags: java, regex, polynomials

here is my code

```
String a = "X^5+2X^2+3X^3+4X^4";
String exp[]=a.split("(|\\+\\d)[xX]\\^");
for(int i=0;i<exp.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("exp: "+exp[i]+" ");
}
```

im try to find the output which is 5,2,3,4
but instead i got this answer

```
exp:
exp:5
exp:2
exp:3
exp:4
```

i dont know where is the first line space come from, and i cannot find a will to get rid of that, i try to use others regex for this and also use  compile,still can get rid of the first line, i try to use new string  "X+X^5+2X^2+3X^3+4X^4";the first line shows exp:X.
and i also use online regex compiler to try my problem, but their answer is 5,2,3,4, buy eclipse give a space ,and then 5,2,3,4 ,need a help to figure this out

Comment: I find this site super helpful when it comes to dealing with regex https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), e.g:

```
    String input = "X^5+2X^2+3X^3+4X^4";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\^([0-9]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    for (int i = 1; matcher.find(); i++) {
        System.out.println("exp: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
```

It gives output:

```
exp: 5
exp: 2
exp: 3
exp: 4
```

How does it work:
Pattern used: \^([0-9]+)
Which matches any strings starting with `^` followed by 1 or more digits (note the `+` sign). Dash (`^`) is prefixed with backslash (`\`) because it has a special meaning in regular expressions - beginning of a string - but in Your case You just want an exact match of a `^` character.

We want to wrap our matches in a groups to refer to them late during matching process. It means we need to mark them using parenthesis `(` and `)`.

Then we want to pu our pattern into Java `String`. In `String` literal, `\`character  has a special meaning - it is used as a control character, eg  `"\n"` represents a new line. It means that if we put our pattern into `String` literal, we need to escape a `\` so our pattern becomes: `"\\^([0-9]+)"`. Note double `\`.

Next we iterate through all matches getting group 1 which is our number match. Note that a  `^`.character is not covered in our match even if it is a part of our pattern. It is so because wr used parenthesis to mark our searched group, which in our case are only digits

Comment: yes, it fit my need ,but if that so , how do u express the coe?

Comment: What do You mean by "express"? You mean "explain"?

Comment: @RexHuang Better?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the `split` method which looks for the occurrence of the regex and, well.. splits the string at this position. Your string starts with `X^` so it very much matches your regex.